# How to implement a log?

Tags: c, linux, logging

I am finding a way to implement a log mechanism that several processes write their behaviors (mainly for error and execution sequence of processes) to it by C with Linux?

Just open a file that shared for multi-processes and let processes fprintf() to it? Any smart way to implement an option/mechanism that controls the level of log such as error/detail/high or something like it?

It would be better if you could refer me to a light opensource for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`syslog`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/syslog.html), it's the standard (POSIX) logging solution.

Answer (score 2):

In other languages, [log4c](http://log4c.sourceforge.net/) is very popular (log4j, log4net). It has a lot of functionality just baked in, and since it is so common, other developers who work on your code will be familiar with it.

Answer (score 1):

Using fprintf is ok, however I am not sure if fprintf is threadsafe, if not use a lock mechanism to block the fprintf call for multiple simultaneous accesses.